# Create a DLL exposing python code

Tags: python, c, plugins, cython

Can I use cython to create a shared library with exported C functions that have python code as the core? Like wrapping Python with C??

It is to be used in plugins.
tk

Comment: You are on the right tracks, mentioning Cython. Dig into it ;). http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/language_basics.html

Comment: Did you find a satisfying solution to your problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Cython, you can write function declared as C ones with the `cdef` keyword (and `public`... important!), with Python inner code:

**yourext.pyx**

```
cdef int public func1(unsigned long l, float f):
    print(f)       # some python code
```

*Note: in the following is assumed that we are working in the root of drive D:\*

**Building** (setup.py)

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext
setup(
      cmdclass = {'build_ext': build_ext},
      name = 'My app',
      ext_modules = cythonize("yourext.pyx"),
)
```

Then run `python setup.py build_ext --inplace`

After running the [setup.py](http://docs.cython.org/src/quickstart/build.html) (if you are using `distutils`), you'll get 2 files of interest:

- yourext.h
- yourext.c

Looking into the `.c` will show you that `func1` is a C function, in the end.

Those two files are all we need to do the rest.

**C main program for testing**

```
// test.c
#include "Python.h"
#include "yourext.h"

main()
{
    Py_Initialize(); // start python interpreter
    inityourext();   // run module yourext

    func1(12, 3.0);  // Lets use shared library...

    Py_Finalize();
}
```

As we don't use the extension (`.pyd`) by itself, we need to make a little trick/hack in the header file to disable the "DLL behavior". Add the following at the beginning of "yourext.h":

```
#undef DL_IMPORT            # Undefines DL_IMPORT macro
#define DL_IMPORT(t) t      # Redefines it to do nothing...

__PYX_EXTERN_C DL_IMPORT(int) func1(unsigned long, float);
```

**Compiling "yourext" as a shared library**

```
gcc -shared yourext.c -IC:\Python27\include -LC:\Python27\libs -lpython27 -o libyourext.dll
```

**Then compiling our test program** (linking to the DLL)

```
gcc test.c -IC:\Python27\include -LC:\Python27\libs -LD:\ -lpython27 -lyourext -o test.exe
```

**Finally, run the program**

```
$ test
3.0
```

This is not obvious, and there is many other ways to achieve the same thing, but this works (have a look to [boost::python](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/python/doc/tutorial/doc/html/python/embedding.html), ..., other solutions may better fit your needs).

I hope this answers a little bit your question or, at least, gave you an idea...

Comment: Thanks a lot for the exhaustive answer.. I'm going trough it. Seem good

Comment: Ok, please keep us posted (even if your final solution is not Cython, I'm interested!), and do not hesitate to `answer your own question` if you get interesting results with Cython...